# SQL Server : Obtener solo personal inactivo según fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, mssql

Hola por favor me ayudan con el siguiente resultado esperado en SQL Server:

Tabla Estado_personal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una persona puede ser contratada muchas veces por una empresa, la persona que esta inactiva es porque su ultimo contrato tiene fecha de termino,  la persona que tiene un contrato activo está vigente entonces no tiene fecha de termino(NULL) al día de hoy.

La query debe devolver solo los que están inactivos actualmente, que no tienen posterior un contrato activo, debiese traer solo el ultimo contrato ordenado por fecha_termino de  : EDGARDO, MARCELO

Resultado Esperado :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya agradeceré cualquier ayuda o guía, gracias.

```
create table #personal (rut nvarchar(12), nombre nvarchar(40), estado nvarchar(40), fecha_inicio date, fecha_termino date, empresa nvarchar(50)) 
insert into #personal values ('RUT1','EDGARDO','inactivo','2017-01-15','2017-01-27','EMPRESA1')
insert into #personal values ('RUT1','EDGARDO','inactivo','2020-07-02','2020-08-25','EMPRESA2')
insert into #personal values ('RUT1','EDGARDO','inactivo','2020-10-02','2020-12-14','EMPRESA1')
insert into #personal values ('RUT2','JUAN','inactivo','2016-02-20','2019-03-10','EMPRESA2')
insert into #personal values ('RUT2','JUAN','inactivo','2020-01-01','2020-12-31','EMPRESA1')
insert into #personal values ('RUT2','JUAN','activo','2021-01-02',null,'EMPRESA2')
insert into #personal values ('RUT3','PEDRO','inactivo','2020-02-10','2020-10-10','EMPRESA1')
insert into #personal values ('RUT3','PEDRO','activo','2021-01-20',null,'EMPRESA1')
insert into #personal values ('RUT4','MARCELO','inactivo','2019-01-01','2020-12-31','EMPRESA2')
SELECT * FROM #personal order by rut, fecha_inicio asc
drop table #personal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrego consulta comentada.

```
select
    rut, nombre, estado, fecha_inicio, fecha_termino, empresa
from (
   select
        -- con esto se genera un numero por fila creando una particion por rut
        -- ( se usa el rut porque es un identificador único ) 
        -- esa partición se ordena por fecha_termino de manera que las filas con
        -- el número 1 siempre serán las que tengan la fecha mayor
        ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by rut order by fecha_termino desc) row,
        *
    from #personal p
    -- esta condición excluye a los que tienen un contrato activo
    where not exists (
        select 1
        from #personal p1
        where fecha_termino is null and p1.rut = p.rut
    )
)t1
-- se filtra la subconsulta por la fila  número 1 y eso devuelve
-- los registros con las fechas más altas
where row = 1
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Lobos por tu ayuda, tu query funciona sin problemas al igual que la respuesta anterior de Lamak, la marque como respuesta porque evito usar las CTE.

Comment: Hola Lobos, buen día. Consulta : Como puedo lograr obtener ahora solo los activos?

Answer (score 1):

Esto lo puedes lograr de forma relativamente simple usando `ROW_NUMBER` y `NOT EXISTS`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rut ORDER BY p.fecha_termino DESC) 
    FROM #personal p
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #personal
                     WHERE rut = p.rut
                     AND fecha_termino IS NULL)
)
SELECT 
    rut,
    nombre,
    estado,
    fecha_inicio,
    fecha_termino,
    empresa
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Lamak, efectivamente funciona sin problemas!!! Gracias por tu tiempo y conocimiento.!,